# Open external url in safari on iPad using Phonegap

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

I'm trying to launch Safari on an iPad app (developed using PhoneGap and Xcode) and I'm experiencing problems, I have I believe, whitelisted the domains in the Cordova.plist and have added a * to enable all (the app will not be release on the App store so I am not worried about Apples rules around this, it is external only) but when simulating the app I receive the following error...

```
2012-08-10 16:56:29.130 WG[17662:13403] OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set: opening in webview
2012-08-10 16:56:30.689 WG[17662:13403] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

Does anyone know whats this means and/or what is going wrong here?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code? To open stuff in safari you need to call this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]
```